# Download video from Twitter using Twitter API without using thirdparty library

Tags: python, twitterapi-python

I'm trying to download this video from Twitter using Twitter API https://twitter.com/Google/status/1257326183101980673 . When I searched extended entities is supposed to have the media files. But, for the mentioned link in the get status API, extended entities are not available in the response.

here is the response of /statuses/show.json - https://textuploader.com/18p95

Could anyone help me in the direction to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the url you are making a request to should be the `video itself` or `some url that has a response with media files`. maybe you need to scrap de page and find the url that is hosting that video. keep in mind that the video may not be `publicly` available for the user. (meaning that you can only view, not download it)

Comment: found the url!
at `xpath`: `//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div/article/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/video`

the video can be found at url: `blob:https://twitter.com/fbecbc87-a1a5-4a94-991c-cca33e668657`

but when i enter the url without blob, it doesnt exist. so just twitter is able to get this video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extended entities will be hidden for large tweet texts it seems to see all the parameters including media_URL, I had added tweet_mode as extended to the API end point

GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=1257326183101980673&tweet_mode=extended

I hope this helps if someone looking at the same problem